# PyQt5 set toolTip for each QTreeView

Tags: pyqt

I make a file browser used TreeView, fileSystemModel
Qtreeview.setTooltip is all item set same tooltip
Only Selected Item set Tooltip possible?

Comment: It depends on what you want to display as tooltip and according to what. QFileSystemModel doesn't directly support the feature, but it can be implemented in a subclass. Another possibility is to intercept `QEvent.ToolTip` in the `event()` of the view or by installing an event filter. If you clarify what is your final purpose and provide a possible example scenario of what should happen, we might be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class tree_item(QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, column, text):
        super().__init__()

        self.setText(column, text)
        self.setToolTip(column, text)

class main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tree = QTreeWidget()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tree)

        self.tree.setHeaderHidden(True)

        self.item1 = tree_item(0, "Item 1")
        self.item2 = tree_item(0, "Item 2")
        self.item3 = tree_item(0, "Item 3")

        self.tree.addTopLevelItems([self.item1, self.item2, self.item3])


        self.resize(800,500)
        self.show()


app = QApplication([])
window = main()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class tree_item(QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, column, text):
        super().__init__()

        self.setText(column, text)

class main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tree = QTreeWidget()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tree)

        self.tree.setHeaderHidden(True)

        self.item1 = tree_item(0, "Item 1")
        self.item2 = tree_item(0, "Item 2")
        self.item3 = tree_item(0, "Item 3")

        self.tree.addTopLevelItems([self.item1, self.item2, self.item3])
        self.tree.currentItemChanged.connect(self.change)


        self.resize(800,500)
        self.show()

    def change(self, e_next, e_prev):
        e_next.setToolTip(0,"ToolTip")

        if e_prev != None:
            e_prev.setToolTip(0,"")
        


app = QApplication([])
window = main()
app.exec()
```